# Put libraries for spring boot application in extra lib dir

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I am currently building my spring boot application as a fat jar. But because I am also building a docker image from these, I have to pull the jar with all its dependencies every time I change some of my code. So my question is: How would I have to change my gradle files to get a task called 'buildWithExternalLibs' that has all dependencies in a lib folder, but can still be started using `java -jar ...` as long as the lib folder is right next to the jar?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in maven project. You can use same logic in gradle too.
When you will clean install, it will copy your jar file too.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>install</phase>
        <id>install-jar-lib</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>install-file</goal>
         </goals>
        <configuration>
          <groupId>com.***.*</groupId>
          <artifactId>abc-library</artifactId>
          <version>*.*.*</version>
          <packaging>jar</packaging>
          <file>${project.basedir}/src/lib/***.jar</file>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
  </executions>
 <inherited>false</inherited>
</plugin>
```